# How to configure dockercloud/haproxy for docker compose when linked service uses network_mode=host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, haproxy, plumber

I have a plumber service and use [dockercloud/haproxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockercloud/haproxy) for load balancing. I use docker-compose for running my Docker applications:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  plumber:
    image: registry.code.roche.com/tmbd/tsi-api:latest
    command: /plumber.R
    volumes:
     - ./plumber/plumber.R:/plumber.R
    restart: always

  lb:
    image: 'dockercloud/haproxy:latest'
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    links:
     - plumber
    ports:
     - 80:80
```

It works fine with this configuration. Now I have extended my `plumber.R` script to communicate with a MongoDB on a remote server to which I established a SSH tunnel with

```
autossh -M 20000 -L 9999:localhost:27017 <user>@<mongodb-server> -vN -p22
```

In addition I added the `network_mode: host` to the plumber service config in the yml file to make it work.

However, according to [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links) `network_mode: host` cannot be mixed with `links` and docker-compose gives the following error message:

```
lb_1   | [ALERT] 208/120346 (9) : parsing [/haproxy.cfg:41] : 'server tsi-api_plumber_1' : could not resolve address 'tsi-api_plumber_1'.
```

I tried different things but it didn't work. Can someone help with adapting the docker-compose.yml to tell the load balance which service to balance?

Comment: `links:` are obsolete and you shouldn't need them at all; `network_mode: host` generally disables Docker networking and means you won't be able to talk to the other container.  Do you need to add MongoDB to this container stack, or to use one of the techniques in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) to connect to a process on the host system?

Comment: The MongoDB is running on another server to which I have set up a tunnel with `autossh -M 20000    -L 9999:localhost:27017 <user>@<mongodb-server> -vN -p22`. I.e. I want to access localhost:9999 from within my plumber Docker container.

Comment: The local system, the remote server, and the application container each think they're `localhost`.  You might need to set the `ssh -L` tunnel listener to listen somewhere other than the physical host's localhost interface, because of details of the Docker networking layer.

Comment: Regarding `links`, I haven't found another solution so far to tell dockercloud/haproxy which service to balance.

Comment: Thanks David. I could make it work by adding the docker host IP address on the docker0 network interface `172.17.0.1` to the tunnel to `ssh -L 172.17.0.1:9999:localhost:27017 <user>@<mongodb-server> -vN -p22` and also in my R script  mongo(...url = "mongodb://172.17.0.1:9999"...). No `network_mode: host` is needed. Still, I couldn't find any alternative for `links` yet that works with dockercloud/haproxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically followed the instructions by David (see comments above) and at [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

1. Get Docker host IP address on `docker0` network interface (in this example `172.17.0.1`) with `ip addr show docker0`
2. Establish SSH tunnel with `ssh -L 172.17.0.1:9999:localhost:27017 <user>@<mongodb-server> -vN -p22`
3. In my plumber R script I changed the Mongo URL to `mongo(...url = "mongodb://172.17.0.1:9999"...)`

No `network_mode: host` is needed.